# mysql python retreive specific column from specific row

Tags: python, mysql

I have an database called sportschool and one record looks like this

ID  Logouttime Logintime totaltime

What i want to do is for example where id is 1(this can be different depending on the user input)
is retreive the logintime and store that in a variable

This is what i have now:

```
aa= pymysql.connect(host='',user='',passwd='',db='',)
mm = aa.cursor()
mm.execute('SELECT Logouttime FROM sportschool WHERE ID = 1')
```

but how can i store it in a variable then?
Insert works fine but i need to retreive the data and store it so i can calculate the difference betwheen logintime and loguittime

Hope someone can help

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the line

```
logouttime = mm.fetchone()
```

More info here:
http://pymssql.org/en/stable/pymssql_examples.html

Comment: Thanks for the command i did what you said But when i print logguittime it prints it like this: {u'loguittime': datetime.timedelta(0, 58981)} in phpmyadmin it stands like this: 16:23:01

Answer (score 0):

```
logouttime = mm.fetchone()
```

it will give you tuple of tuple

```
    (("10:00:00"))
```

now you can do whatever you want with that logout time

```
>>> import datetime
>>> a = {u'loguittime': datetime.timedelta(0, 58981)}
>>> a['loguittime']
     datetime.timedelta(0, 58981)
>>> d = a['loguittime']
>>> (d.days, d.seconds, d.microseconds)
    (0, 58981, 0)
```

Comment: Thanks for the command i did what you said
@BloodringBanger
But when i print logguittime it prints it like this:
{u'loguittime': datetime.timedelta(0, 58981)}

in phpmyadmin it stands like this: 16:23:01

Comment: thats the problem with date time you need to parse it and then you can perform operations onto it

Comment: And by any change do you know how to do that?

Comment: This is something that is easily found by a google search I suppose. Try "parsing datetime python". Good luck!

Comment: @Klaas see this is how you will parse